# Можно ли закруглить меню?

Tags: css

Можно ли закруглить меню? я ставлю вот такой код в style.css

```
.SuperMenu
    {
    border-radius:10px;
    }
```

и перед меню я пишу вот такой скрипт: **<div class="SuperMenu">**
в конце закрываю тегу **</div>**

```
    <a href="#">Текст</a>

и так далее...
```

но у меня всё равно  не получается! У меня стиль вертикального меню "**Лава-лампа**"
вот скрин:
http://s41.radikal.ru/i093/1207/1b/4d6f70b9b7ba.jpg

Comment: Оффтоп: не первый раз вижу Ваши вопросы и не первый раз хочу подправить, что в именительном падеже правильно говорить `тег`, а не `тега`, следовательно, "...закрываю `тег`", а не "...закрываю `тегу`". Это раздражает собеседников.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ul{border-radius:20px;}.Для кросса префиксы -moz-,-webkit

Comment: Новые браузеры уже отлично работают c border-radius без префиксов.

Comment: будем знать.Но оно то4но не помешает для юзера у кого старый браузер

Answer (score 1):

Есть отличный генератор - http://www.css3.me/. Пользуйтесь, все будет работать :)